# Imaginary friend from childhood returns when a young woman is in trouble

Tags: identify-this-movie, comedy

It is where a young woman has an emotional crisis in her life, with her cheating boyfriend and controlling mother.

And her imaginary friend from when she was little comes back and causes more chaos for her and nobody else can see him?

I think it's from the 1990's.

Can anyone identify this?

Comment: Do you know any more details?

Comment: the imaginary friend always wore like a green suit with red shoes and i think his name may have been frank? im not sure. @poepje

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After some Googling I found one movie that seems to be pretty much like you described it: [Drop Dead Fred](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101775/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1).

> "A young woman finds her already unstable life rocked by the presence
>   of a rambunctious imaginary friend from childhood."

The imaginary friend here is played by comedy actor Rik Mayall, wearing a green suit.

[image]

Comment: Just to add this is it. Used to love that movie.

Comment: Picture added because Rik makes everything better.

Comment: @Nobby He does indeed, just seeing his goofy face makes me smile :p

Comment: Oh, I remember this movie!  Loved the bit where he wakes the little girl up so they can be burglars together. "I made your jersey stripey!"